How do i validate a duplicate email input using knex?
I'm building an app with node.js knex.js typescript zod and fastify, im trying to validate the emails so that when an email is inserted on the user registration, if it is a duplicate it throws status 401(conflict), but even if the emails does'nt exist it's generating the status, i can't see why it isn't working.
export async function userRegister(
request: FastifyRequest,
reply: FastifyReply,
) {
const registerBodySchema = z.object({
name: z.string(),
email: z.string().email(),
password: z.string().min(6),
});

const { name, email, password} = registerBodySchema.parse(request.body);

const password_hash = await hashSync(password, 6);

const userWithSameEmail = await knex.select('\*').from('users').where('email' , email)

if (userWithSameEmail){
return reply.status(409).send({userWithSameEmail});
}

await knex('usuarios').insert({
id: crypto.randomUUID(),
nome,
email,
password: password_hash,
});
return reply.status(201).send();
}

i tried using getting the email from the table using knex and it responses fine when i test it, the duplicate email shows on the logs
export async function userRegister(
request: FastifyRequest,
reply: FastifyReply,
) {
const registerBodySchema = z.object({
name: z.string(),
email: z.string().email(),
password: z.string().min(6),
});

const { name, email, password} = registerBodySchema.parse(request.body);

const password_hash = await hashSync(password, 6);

const userWithSameEmail = await knex.select('\*').from('users').where('email' , email)

response { userWithSameEmail }

if (userWithSameEmail){
return reply.status(409).send();
}

await knex('usuarios').insert({
id: crypto.randomUUID(),
nome,
email,
password: password_hash,
});
return reply.status(201).send();

But when i remove the response{ userWithSameEmail } and let the code run it only returns status(401) even if the email isn't a duplicate, can someone help?

When you do:
const userWithSameEmail = await knex.select('\*').from('users').where('email' , email);

The result is an array of users.
Then you check the array for truthiness with:
if (userWithSameEmail)…

However in js an empty array [] is truthy.
If there can only ever be one user with a given email then do:
const userWithSameEmail = await knex.select(['*']).from('users').where({ email }).first();

OTOH if there can be several then just check the length of the result array with:
if (userWithSameEmail.length)…

If the array has no elements then .length will be zero which is falsy.
